# Code Composer Studio 6.1.0 debugger is not acting as it should

Tags: msp430, ide, ti-ccstudio

I am learning to code on a microcontroller from Texas Instruments, MSP430FR6969 ([link](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989)), using MSP-EXP430FR6969 launch pad ([link](http://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430FR6989)).

I am also using an IDE CCS 6.1.0 ([link](http://www.ti.com/tools-software/ccs.html)).

I am doing a simple odometer, where the program counts from 0 to 99,999 and then resets again.

code below

```
#include <msp430.h> 

#define DEVELOPMENT 0x5A80
#define ENABLE_PINS 0xFFFE

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = DEVELOPMENT;//disable WDT
    PM5CTL0 = ENABLE_PINS;//this is needed in order to enable pins

    P1DIR = 0x01;//P1.1 is output
    P1OUT = 0x00;//port 1 = 0x00

    unsigned int tnth, thou, hund, tens, ones;

    unsigned long km = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        for(tnth = 0;tnth < 10;tnth++)
        {
            for(thou = 0;thou<10;thou++)
            {
                for(hund = 0;hund<10;hund++)
                {
                    for(tens = 0;tens<10;tens++)
                    {
                        for(ones = 0;ones<10;ones++)
                        {
                            km = 10000*tnth + 1000*thou + 100*hund +10*tens+ 
                            ones;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        P1OUT = ~P1OUT;//I added a breakpoint there.
        km = 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I added a breakpoint at `P1OUT = ~P1OUT;`, build it and debugged it like in the image below.

[image]

When the debugger reaches the breakpoint, I see in the variable watch window ones, tens, hunds, thou, and tnth all equal to 10, which is what I expect.

But I also expected `km = 99999`, instead I have `km = 34463`, which doesn't make sense as `km` is an `unsigned long`

Also.

When I modify the code and change `unsigned int tnth, thou, hund, tens, ones` to `signed int`, put a breakpoint at `P1OUT = ~P1OUT` build it and debug I get   `km = 4294936223` in the variable watch window.

I asked the question in TI forum ([link](https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/706687)), and a member said that in my build

> "../main.c", line 16: warning #552-D: variable "km" was set but never used

Kindly help me on this matter, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Code Composer Studio 8.0 is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your MSP430 is a 16-bit machine, so the compiler is doing the `(10000*tnth)` as a multiplication of 16-bit numbers and truncating the result to 16 bits before continuing with the rest of the calculation.

```
10000 * 9 = 90000 = 0x15F90  
truncate to 16-bits = 0x5F90 = 24464  
24464 + 9999 = 34463
```

If you cast the 10000 integer constant to 32-bits with something like `10000UL` and/or cast the variable with `(unsigned long)tnth` you should see your expected results.

The warning for 'variable "km" was set but never used' is expected.
You're assigning values to `km`, but never reading them back or using `km` in any other way, but this has nothing to do with your undesired behavior.

When you changed your 16-bit data type from unsigned to signed, what happens is that the 34463 (0x869F) value is treated as a negative 16-bit value of -31073 (since the MSB is a 1).
When converting this into a 32-bit value, it first gets sign-extended to a 32-bit signed value - so now it's 0xFFFF869F.
But since you're putting this into an unsigned 32-bit integer variable this value is now represented as 4294936223.

Comment: Any chance of the code being optimized away (by the compiler) because km is never used?

Comment: Some compilers might do that, but the result the OP is getting (34463) is exactly what you'd get when the first multiplication gets truncated to 16-bits, so it looks like it's not being optimized out.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen, Optimization was off

Comment: @brhans  Then how come when I changed unsigned int to int, I get `km > 4000000`, shouldn't I get `34463` as well

Comment: @brahans your answer makes sense for when I get km = 34463, but if I change `unsigned int tnth` to `int tnth`90,000 will still be 24465, which should give me `km = 34463`

Comment: @Forat - see update.